# XSLT / Xpath 2.0

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xpath, timestamp

How to display the current time stamp in the specific format
For eg: 2015-07-29 13:48:18.617365
I have a requirement which I need to pass the Current time stamp in the above format if the requester is not sending it ..

So I have hard coded it for the mean time.

I would like to replace the hard coded date with current date in the above specific date. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 (not XPath 2.0) you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01] [H01]:[m01]:[s01].[f001]')" />
```